# Почему не работает переименование контроллера в ASP.NET с Angular?

Tags: asp.net-core, angular, asp.net-web-api

При создании нового приложения ASP.NET с Angular, в ASP по умолчанию создаётся контроллер WeatherForecastController (доступ к нему через https://localhost:PORT/weatherforecast), в Angular прописывается соответствующее содержимое файла proxy.conf.js:

```
    const PROXY_CONFIG = [
      {
        context: [
          "/weatherforecast",
        ],
        target: "https://localhost:7276",
        secure: false
      }
    ]

    module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Я переименовал контроллер, изменив его со следующим образом (файл с контроллером также переименовал):

```
[ApiController]
[Route("feedback")]
public class FeedBackController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<FeedBackController> _logger;

    public FeedBackController(ILogger<FeedBackController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get() => Ok();

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post() => Ok();
}
```

А также изменил содержимое файла proxy.conf.js:

```
    const PROXY_CONFIG = [
      {
        context: [
          "/feedback",
        ],
        target: "https://localhost:7276",
        secure: false
      }
    ]

    module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Но при попытке вызвать в коде компонента Angular функцию

```
    http.get('/feedback').subscribe(result => alert('OK!'), error => console.error(error));
```

Получаю ошибку:

[image: ошибка браузера]

При этом, стоит вернуть имя weatherforecast, как всё начинает работать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как же его переименовать?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт, решил эту проблему простым запуском фронта с нуля (командой ng serve)